# Scala : Irregular behaviour foldleft() vs foreach()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Just listing out 2 solutions for which I had tried to achieve a use case to apply a spark udf to some of the columns, but I am not sure why both of my functions are behaving totally differently even when I am trying to achieve the same thing. Can someone explain the internal working, as of what exactly is happening in both of these cases?

Function 1:

```
def transformColumns(df: DataFrame, transformationType: String, sanitizationList: List[Sanitization]): DataFrame = {

    try {
      sanitizationList.foldLeft(df) {
        (outerAccumulator: DataFrame, sanitization: Sanitization) =>
          val aes: TAlgorithm = new AES256(key, iv)
          @transient lazy val udfFunction = udf(aes.decrypt(_)
          sanitization.column.foldLeft(outerAccumulator: DataFrame) {
            (innerAccumulator: DataFrame, elem: String) =>
              innerAccumulator.withColumn(elem, when(col(elem).isNotNull, udfFunction(col(elem))).otherwise(lit(null)))
          }
      }
    }
```

Function 2 :

```
def transformColumns(df: DataFrame, columns: Map[Seq[String], TAlgorithm]): DataFrame = {

    try {
      columns.foldLeft(df) {
        (accumulator: DataFrame, sanitization: (Seq[String], TAlgorithm)) =>
          import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
          val aes: TAlgorithm = new AES256(key, iv)
          @transient lazy val udfFunction = udf(aes.decrypt(_))
          sanitization._1.foreach{
            elem => accumulator.withColumn(elem, when(col(elem).isNotNull, udfFunction(col(elem))).otherwise(lit(null)))
          }
          accumulator
      }
    }
```

In the second case none of columns are being transformed, not sure why.

Comment: actually I have not pasted the entire function, but only the logical part, the catch clause is actually there.

Comment: because `df.withColumn` creates a new `DataFrame` instead of modifying the original one. So, its obvious that your `foreach` does nothing to your `accumulator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your 1st example

  ```
  sanitization.column.foldLeft(outerAccumulator: DataFrame) {
    (innerAccumulator: DataFrame, elem: String) =>
      innerAccumulator.withColumn(elem, when(col(elem).isNotNull, udfFunction(col(elem))).otherwise(lit(null)))
  }
  ```

  `foldLeft` evaluates the last line (`innerAccumulator.withColumn...`) that will be in `innerAccumulator:DataFrame` at the next iteration.
- In your 2nd example

  ```
  sanitization._1.foreach{
    elem => accumulator.withColumn(elem, when(col(elem).isNotNull, udfFunction(col(elem))).otherwise(lit(null)))
  }
  ```

  `DataFrame` are immutable, so `withColumn` returns a new `DataFrame`. But since `for_each` returns `Unit`, the new DF created by `accumulator.withColumn` is lost

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now the behaviour makes sense. Can there be a better approach of achieving the same in function 1 ?

Comment: function 1 is the working one and is already a good way to do what you want. In function 2, not sure how to do it (maybe storing `accumulator` in a `var`)

Comment: thanks a lot, basically I had earlier written function 2 but since it was not working, I tried with the approach in function 1.

Comment: @AmanVaishya You'r welcome.  Also, in function 2 , `sanitization._1`  refers to `TAlgorithm` whereas `sanitization._0`  refers to `Seq[String]` and you use `sanitization._1.foreach`